# How to connect to DB in hibernate using JNDI

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I am using jndi/db alias name used to connect to DB. Its working fine.. But, i need to accomplish the same using Hibernate...

I am not able to connect when i use below properties,

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/ASPTADMINDEV</property>
```

And in resurce.xml file, i am using this,

```
(
 <factories xmi:type="resources.jdbc:DataSource" xmi:id="DataSource_1233129165895" name="Oracle JDBC Driver DataSource" jndiName="jdbc/ASPTADMINDEV" description="New JDBC Datasource" providerType="Oracle JDBC Driver" authMechanismPreference="BASIC_PASSWORD" authDataAlias="ccixdmgr-nprd1-01-nodeMgr/GITPTDEV-ASPTADMIN-ASPTI" manageCachedHandles="false" logMissingTransactionContext="true" diagnoseConnectionUsage="false" relationalResourceAdapter="builtin_rra" statementCacheSize="10" datasourceHelperClassname="com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle10gDataStoreHelper">
      <propertySet xmi:id="J2EEResourcePropertySet_1233129165915">
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1233129165915" name="driverType" type="java.lang.String" value="oci8" description="The type of the driver. The possible values are: thin, oci8." required="false"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1233129165916" name="oracleLogFileSizeLimit" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0" description="Oracle10g and beyond: The oracleLogFileSizeLimit specifies the maximum number of bytes to be written to any one file. Property is relevant only if trace file is specified. Default is unlimited" required="false"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1233129165917" name="oracleLogFileCount" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1" description="Oracle10g and beyond: The oracleLogFileCount specifies the number of files to use. Property is relevant only if trace file is specified. Default is 1." required="false"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1233129165918" name="oracleLogFileName" type="java.lang.String" value="" description="Oracle10g and beyond: The oracleLogFileName indicates which file to write the traces to" required="false"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1233129165919" name="oracleLogTraceLevel" type="java.lang.String" value="INFO" description="Oracle10g and beyond: The oracleLogTraceLevel specifies which message "> 
......... and so

}
```

please let me know what i am doing mistake here..

Forget to paste the error ;).. Below is the error, i am getting

```
INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
Apr 9, 2014 4:17:19 PM org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider configure
SEVERE: Could not find datasource: java:comp/env/jdbc/ASPTADMINDEV
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
```

.

Do i need to change any thing. I am using below property

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/ASPTADMINDEV</property>
```

Comment: Where is the application deployed: Tomcat or an application server (which one)? Start debugging yourself, e.g check whether the datasource is correctly registered (check that within your application server)

Comment: Oh, you told in a comment below that you have also a comment. Interesting... Do you really expect us to know what error occurs in your system?

Comment: @AndreiI forget to paste error. ;). I deployed in TOMCAT server, its throwing above error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give correct JNDI name of the data source, try this one.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/ASPTADMINDEV</property>
```

Comment: I tried it but still its throwing error.. Not able to connect to DB

Comment: @Arun Please try to add all relevant details on first post itself. Verify whether datasource & your application are in same context/cell/node etc. I am not much into websphere. Also can you update post with connection properties.

Comment: Now, i have created simple web application with hibernate fw. I am able to connect to db directly providing thin URL directly in hibernate config file. But, when i tried to connect via DB alias. I am getting above error. i have mentioned db alias, jndi names in resource.xml. Do i need to include this in web.xml?

Comment: @Arun Yes, resource-ref in web.xml